# strategy to create 4 bytes unique Id in java

Tags: java

Our java application has a 4 bytes size restriction to hold unique id.

We are forced to implement a strategy to create unique ids which are 4 bytes in size.

Does any one know a strategy to create it

Comment: ints are 4 bytes, why can't you start with random number and increment it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, start with a random 32 bit integer and increment it.

Anything else will be too demanding as you scale up (e.g. if you have 1 billion already created ids and need to randomly generate a new one, you have to have a 1 billion entry table to check for existence inside... ouch!).

But if it absolutely has to be random and unique, the two strategies you can take are:

1) Have a big `HashSet` of every id used so far and check for existence in the set whenever you generate a new random ID. If it is, discard and try again.

2) Store all randomly used IDs in the database, and do a `SELECT` to see if your newly generated random ID exists. If it does, discard and try again.

If the unique ID was larger, you could use a Guid (also known as uuid), which are generated large enough and in such a way that you'll never see two Guids have the same value ever, anywhere, without needing to check.

For Guids/UUIDs in java, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Thanks @Patashu. For now, we decided to use Random.nextInt() with current version due to the 4bytes size limit.

Comment: @Arun Be aware that Random.nextInt() has no guarantee of being unique. If it is mandatory that there be no collision of IDs, every new ID will have to be checked for uniqueness.

Comment: agreed @Patashu. we plan to increase the variable size limit to 32 bytes to accommodate UUID (with no dash -) in the next release. We should be good by then

Answer (score 0):

I think `int` can  meet your demands.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
private static byte[] synhead = {(byte)0xAA,0x55,0x7E,0x0B};
```